# No layers in the exported image of the MXD project using C#

Tags: c#, arcmap, arcobjects

I have created a console application to export the active view of an MXD document using C# ArcObjects. The app works, but for some reason the exported image is missing all the layers in the map and legend. I checked, all layers are enabled, the problem is in the export implementation.

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Output;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Display;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Resources;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMap;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;

namespace firstConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        private static LicenseInitializer m_AOLicenseInitializer = new firstConsole.LicenseInitializer();

        [STAThread()]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
            //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
            m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication(new esriLicenseProductCode[] { esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic },
            new esriLicenseExtensionCode[] { });
            //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
            //Do not make any call to ArcObjects after ShutDownApplication()
            m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication();

            IPrintAndExport export = new PrintAndExportClass();

            string mxd = @"C:\0_Work\Test\3.mxd";

            tagRECT exporterRectangle;
            exporterRectangle.left = 0;
            exporterRectangle.bottom = 1654;
            exporterRectangle.top = 0;
            exporterRectangle.right = 2340;
            var expOptions = new ExportJPEGClass();
            expOptions.Quality = 75;
            expOptions.Resolution = 200;
            IMapDocument pMapDocument = new MapDocumentClass();
            expOptions.ExportFileName = mxd.Replace("mxd", "jpg");
            pMapDocument.Open(mxd, null);
            IActiveView activeView = pMapDocument.ActiveView;
            export.Export(activeView, expOptions, 200, false, null);
            pMapDocument.Close();
        }
    }
}
```